# Python multi inheritance super__init__(**kwargs)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am newbie , I have such a question , in this code

```
class One:
    def __init__(self, x, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x = x**2


class Two:
    def __init__(self, y, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.y = y**3


class Three(One, Two):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print(self.y, self.x)


Three(x=1, y=2)
```

I understood how **kwargs works , but cant understand why need to call parents init function in
classes  One and Two . In my case in class One and class Two as I see  **kwargs is just empty
dict.  Why need I   super().**init**(**kwargs) , if kwargs is just empty dict

I tried another ways too , without kwargs

```
class Three(One, Two):
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        One.__init__(self,x)
        Two.__init__(self,y)
        print(self.y, self.x)
```

This way is easier to Undertstand , But Can anyone Explain how it works with **kwargs . Thanks

Comment: `super` is a misleading name. It calls the *next implementation in the method resolution order*, not the superclass's implementation. ("The superclass" isn't even a well-defined concept in multiple inheritance.)

Comment: Try printing it and you will see that it is not always an empty dictionary.

Comment: "In my case in class One and class Two as I see **kwargs is just empty dict. " Why do you think so? Did you test it?

Comment: yes, I added print(kwargs)   and answer was {}

Comment: [No it wasn't.](https://ideone.com/dZLr16)

Comment: @kaya3 how did you find this duplicate? I typically get terrible results with the search here, and this time was no exception.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I searched for `[python] super kwargs` and it was about the 10th result sorted by relevance. The rest were relevant, just not close enough to be duplicates. I find it a lot easier to do a search in a separate tab, rather than use the search built into the "close as duplicate" dialogue which is rather hard to use.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you could just do:

```
class Three(One, Two):
    pass
```

Unless you really have something specific to implement in Three at instanciation time

However, you need to leave **kwargs on your 2 parent classes as their `__init__` will receive all the non-defined keyword arguments passed to `Three.__init__`

Advice: use a debugger, like PyCharm/VSCode to visualize what happens when the instance gets created, that really nice to observe how the code runs.

`super` is just a way to let Python decide in which order the parent classes method will be called (MRO)

When python executes `Three(x=1, y=2)` it actually sends to Three.**init** 3 things:

1. self: instance being instanciated
2. a tuple of positional args (commonly named `args`)
3. a dict of keyword args (commonly named `kwargs`)

In your case, as you only used keyword arguments, `args` will be an empty tuple and kwargs will be `{'x': 1, 'y': 2}`

Then:

1. `One.__init__(x, **kwargs)` will take `x` and leave `y` inside kwargs
2. `Two.__init__(y, **kwargs)` will take `y` and leave `x` inside kwargs

Comment: But what super().__init__(**kwargs) do ? 
when I print(kwargs)    in class One and Two , its just empty dict   {}

So why is necessary to call    objects initial function with empty dict as argument ?

Comment: "But what super().__init__(\*\*kwargs) do ?" Did you try copying and pasting that into a search engine? "when I print(kwargs) in class One and Two , its just empty dict {}" No, it is not. In `One`, you get a `y` key because it hasn't been assigned to a named argument yet. The `super` call allows that information to be passed to `Two.__init__`. The `super` magic is designed in a way that lets that happen *even though `One` doesn't know about `Two`*, because the *object* being `__init__`ed is a `Three` (which does know about both).